# How to choose an electromagnet controlled by sound signal

Tags: electromagnetism

I've asked here before but I was told to be more specific so here I go.

I would like to build an electromagnet that I can control with sound input, more or less like a speaker but safe and powerfull enough to move things around.

For example: the electromagnet would be attached to bottom of a 10 x 10 cm glass box filled with iron fillings. Based on the sound signal (soft / loud) the electromagnet would have varying strength and those irong fillings would move around based on that.

I was thinking I would just connect the electromagnet to my guitar amplifier

(It has Hammond Manufacturing 125DSE audio trasformator (http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/125DSE/125DSE-ND/454501) and has 4 / 8 / 16 ohm outputs. The speaker curently attached to it is 60W, 8ohm)

but I have no idea what should I be making. I was told that only option was AC type of EM but I am not sure about the specifics in order not to destroy the AMP and to have magnet powerfull enough to move those iron fillings and to be able to be on for hours without overheating.

Any advice on the magnet would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain in detail what you expect the iron filings to do. Until this is grasped I, for one, have no idea what type of electromagnet might be suitable. Please reference the effects of different frequencies and what you expect the filings to do/perform.

Comment: I was just hoping they would sort of bounce around the box (if it was half full of them)  depending on the strength. Good representation would be here (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1QVijlS-aYg) where the liquid would rise and fall based on the strength. Thats sort of the power Im looking for, probably a little bit more. But Im sorry, Im not sure what you mean by "reference the effects of different frequencies ".

Comment: They are using a DC field to attract the magnetizable fluid. I don't know what you are expecting to achieve therefore I can't recommend something to produce an effect that I don't understand.

Comment: I want to achieve exactly that. Except I want to be able to control the intesity with sound signal.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer,  I am not sure though if I understand corectly. Well to be honest Im lost completely. Doesnt the AMP I have mentioned already turning the AC signal into DC? And if not that means that first I have AC sound signal then I convert it to DC signal and then feed it to amplifier and then into the electro magnet? Could I still use the mentioned amplifier?

Comment: Also, I just tried to use the electromagnet from the speaker but the electromagnet was too weak. Is there anything I can do? As in amplify the AC signal from the amplifier and then into the electromagnet? Or maybe just puting in stronger AC magnet?

Answer (score 1):

Take a large air-code choke like from a loudspeaker cross-over and see if that does what you want.  try with and without a bridge rectifier.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you mean something like this http://www.parts-express.com/jantzen-audio-11mh-18-awg-air-core-inductor-crossover-coil--255-252 ? So it is basically the same as the normal electromagnet in the speaker? And do I just connect it in a same way as I would connect the speaker?And how do I choose the specifics?

Comment: probably best to add a 4 ohm  power resistor in series,  (or whatever the lowest speaker impedance your amplifier likes is)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to be able to control the intesity with sound signal.

Ah that's very different. You need a DC electromagnet and you need to convert your AC signal to a variable DC value using something like precision rectifier - this is based around an op-amp and depending on the amplitude of your signal rising or falling, the dc output will rise or fall. Next you feed the output into a DC amplifier (this can also be built around a power op-amp). You'll need a DC power supply too.